# selectionStart-End with textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, selection-api

I'm having this annoying problem, I can't seem to get the starting and ending index of the selected text in a textarea, all I get is undefined like this:

```
$('#myarea').selectionStart; // return undefined
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#myarea')[0].selectionStart;
```

Why? A jQuery selector does not return the actual DOM elements but the wrapped jQuery collection. jQuery makes the actual DOM elements accessible as an array, so if you wanted to use the 1st matched element (and in this case, the only one, since it's by ID), you would do the above.

Comment: This was the final piece of my morning JS puzzle. You sir, are a life saver!

By the way, for anyone wanting to use this in order to automatically replace certain characters in an input field while maintaining the caret position: remember to apply the [0] to your "setSelectionRange" as well.

Answer (score 18):

Since jQuery version 1.6, you can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

Get:

```
// always start at 0

var start = $('#myarea').prop('selectionStart');
var end = $('#myarea').prop('selectionEnd');
```

Set:

```
$('#myarea').prop('selectionStart', 10);
$('#myarea').prop('selectionEnd', 15);

// or short hand by

$('#myarea').prop({
    'selectionStart': 10,
    'selectionEnd': 15
});
```

Comment: Don't want to be pushy, but what advantages does this have over the native property? O.o There aren't any compatibility issues with the native one and I only see it being even longer and surely also slower..