# How can I utilize selectionStart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textselection, selection-api

As I understood, selectionStart must return start position from selected text in input text or textarea elements

I have this js code

```
 $("#inpt").on("mouseup" , function () {
    alert( $("#inpt").selectionStart);
});
```

and html

```
<input id="inpt" type="text" value="bla bla bla" />
```

When I select some part in text "bla bla bla" the result is "undefined". Yell please, where did I go wrong ?

Comment: `selectionStart` is a DOM element property, not a jQuery object's..

Comment: here solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714830/selectionstart-end-with-textareas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `this.selectionStart`, it's not the property of jQuery object, but the `HTMLInputElement`'s property.

```
$("#inpt").on("mouseup" , function () {
    console.log(this.selectionStart);
});
```

Comment: this.selectionStart is undefined in my case  , can you tell me what can be the possible reasons?