# Cursor is not positioning correctly In Mozilla

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

When I'm filling the field first name and then I'm using the tab to fill the field "Firstnames", the cursor is before the last name.This is happening just on Mozilla.  `Here is my` [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/NBgZtdq0Qy7YBvaM9SLG?p=preview).

Comment: where is your code ???

Comment: Here is the code https://plnkr.co/edit/NBgZtdq0Qy7YBvaM9SLG?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the selectionStart and selectionEnd fields are actually doing anything in your code because you are setting it on the jQuery object instead of the DOM element.  I think the other browsers just default to putting the cursor at the end of the field.

Instead, call get(0) or [0] to get the actual DOM element when setting the selection range.

Replace this code:

```
var selection = firstnamesField.val().length-1;
firstnamesField.selectionStart = selection;
firstnamesField.selectionEnd = selection;
```

With

```
var selection = firstnamesField.val().length;
firstnamesField[0].selectionStart = selection;
firstnamesField[0].selectionEnd = selection;
```

Similar StackOverflow post:

[selectionStart-End with textareas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714830/selectionstart-end-with-textareas)