# ASP.NET - VB.NET - Selectionstart

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know, there is no built in RichTextBox in ASP.NET (I am using Visual Studio, and visual basic), but I want to use **Selectionstart** and **Selectionlength** "methode". When it is possible, then for multiline textbox.

Is there any way for it?

I am searching the internet for it a long time, but I did not find a solution.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Does that mean you want the start of string and length of string entered inside textbox?

Comment: If I have a text with a lot of words, I want to select one of them in the length I gave. For examle: "Have a nice day, sir" --> I want to select the word "nice" and +2 character = "nice d"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selectionStart-End with textareas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714830/11683)

Comment: I want to make somethink like that, but in asp.net:
        Dim a As String
        Dim b As String
        a = TextBox2.Text
        b = InStr(RichTextBox1.Text, a)
        If b Then
            RichTextBox1.Focus()

            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = b - 1
            RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = Len(Textbox3.Text)
        End If